# WebScraping: Pandas to_excel Not Displaying full DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, jupyter

I am brand new to coding, and was given a web scraping tutorial (found [here](https://oxylabs.io/blog/python-web-scraping)) to help build my skills as I learn. I've already had to make several adjustments to the code in this tutorial, but I digress. I'm scraping off of http://books.toscrape.com/ and, when I try to export a Dataframe of just the book categories into Excel, I get a couple of issues. Note that, when exporting to csv (and then opening the file in Notepad), these issues are not present. I am working in a Jupyter Notebook in Azure Data Studio.

First, the row with all the data appears to not exist, even though it is displayed, making it so that I have to tab over to each column to go past the data that is shown in the default windowsize of Excel.
Second, it only displays the first 9 results (the first being "Books," and the other 8 being the first 8 categories).

[Image of desired scrape section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R92ig.png)

Here is my code:

```
s = Service('C:/Users/.../.../chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/'
browser.get(url)
results = []
content = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
# changes from the tutorial due to recommendations
# from StackOverflow, based on similar questions
# from error messages popping up when using original
# formatting; tutorial is outdated. 

for li in soup.find_all(attrs={'class': 'side_categories'}):
    name = element.find('li')
    if name not in results:
        results.append(name.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Categories': results})
df.to_excel('categories.xlsx', index=False)
# per https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel.html
# encoding is Deprecated and apparently wasn't
# needed for any excel writer other than xlwt,
# which is no longer maintained.
```

Images of results:

[View before tabbing further in the columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq3AU.png)

[End of the displayed results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVBN5.png)

What can I do to fix this?

Edit: Many apologies, I didn't realize I have copied an older, incorrect version of my code blocks. Should be correct now.

Comment: name = a.find('a')?

Comment: On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Comment: @Renaud I actually made a mistake when copying my code over, which I didn't realize until seeing your message! So thanks for that! It should have been searching for li instead of a in the first place. But I can also see if your suggestion helps with that in mind, while also updating my post accordingly! Thanks!

Comment: @HedgeHog Oh, sorry! My bad. Was the image of the Excel portion also a no-no in this mind? Or is there perhaps a better way I can present the output into Excel on here? Apologies again!

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect my actual code in its current form. Apologies for the mistake there.

Comment: @Flintzer0 Not per se, with appropriate support from reproducible data, it would be okay from my point of view - Providing result of `df.to_dict()` would already map these quite well in the approach, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in question will not create any dataframe. However, you should select your elements more specific for example with [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for a in soup.select('ul.nav-list a'):
    if a.get_text(strip=True) not in results:
        results.append(a.get_text(strip=True))
```

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

results = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://books.toscrape.com/').content)

for a in soup.select('ul.nav-list a'):
    if a.get_text(strip=True) not in results:
        results.append(a.get_text(strip=True))

pd.DataFrame({'Categories': results})
```

##### Output

|  | Categories |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Books |
| 1 | Travel |
| 2 | Mystery |
| 3 | Historical Fiction |
| 4 | Sequential Art |
| 5 | Classics |
| 6 | Philosophy |

...

Comment: Awesome, that created what I was intending! Can I ask what about what I had previously done made it not work? Just trying to understand the functions better so I can know for the future.

Comment: I find it difficult to work through it in its entirety, as various things are interdependent and the dokus of the modules or tutorials are much more suitable for this. Try your posted code once, the error messages are self-explanatory. First hint - you are trying to find something in `element`, but `element` is not defined anywhere, at the beginning it would have been `a`, now after editing your code it should be `li`.

Comment: OH MY GOSH How did I _miss_ that? Looking back at the tutorial I was using, I'm not even sure why I had changed the for "" in BeautifulSoup away from element like it has. (Edit: Though, that still returns with the same problem in Excel, whereas your solution is much better.) Well. Thank you very much for your help! If I could upvote your answer, I would do it twice.

Comment: Like I said I would before, I now have enough reputation to upvote you! So take it!